# Understanding rules - false as answer

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I am new in Prolog and I was just thinking that why this rule giving me false result after one true.

`likes(1,banana).`
`likes(1,mango).`

`test :- likes(1,banana),likes(1,mango).`

```
?- test.  
true;  
false.
```

I want to know the reason behind this false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way prolog works is by evaluating queries until a fail by negation.

Here, you've established two facts:

`likes(1, banana).` which says "1 likes banana"

`likes(1, mango).` which says "1 likes mango"

Then you have established a rule, which basically evaluates as:

`left_hand_side :- right_hand_side.` `left_hand_side` **if** `right_hand_side`

Evaluation of the rule as a query tries to match facts and returns `true` if it can, and false if it cannot match. One important thing to note is that, if specified, prolog will continue to match facts as long as rules evaluate to `true`.

So let's step through `test :- likes(1,banana),likes(1,mango).`

If `test` is run as a query, prolog first tries `likes(1,banana)` which is a previously established fact, and is true. Then, it moves on to `likes(1,mango)` which, again, is a fact, and is true. Prolog has then reached the end of the rule, and outputs `true`.

At this point, if you're not searching for more matches you can cut the query short and just have true. However, if you're looking for more (all) matches, prolog **backtracks** and tries to evaluate the rule again, searching for more matches.

However, since your rule is only matching "likes banana and likes mango" and we already matched `likes(1,banana)`, when prolog backtracks and tries evaluating `likes(1,banana)` again, since we already matched it before, this time there is not another fact (in other words, 1 cannot "like" banana more than once, unless that has been defined) to match. So that's where the `false` comes from.

In your prolog interpreter you may be able to trace the execution of your program by typing `trace.` then running your query. My trace is given below:

```
| ?- trace
.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)

(1 ms) yes
{trace}
| ?- test.
      1    1  Call: test ? 
      2    2  Call: likes(1,banana) ? 
      2    2  Exit: likes(1,banana) ? 
      3    2  Call: likes(1,mango) ? 
      3    2  Exit: likes(1,mango) ? 
      1    1  Exit: test ? 

true ? ;
      1    1  Redo: test ? 
      2    2  Redo: likes(1,banana) ? 
      2    2  Fail: likes(1,banana) ? 
      1    1  Fail: test ? 

(1 ms) no
{trace}
| ?-
```

One last thing to note: If, instead of pressing `;` at the `true ?` prompt, had I pressed `<ENTER>`, the script would have finished with only the `true`.

I'm glad you asked this question 'cause it allowed me a tiny refresher on prolog, which I really like but haven't used in a long time.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed description. Actually previously I was not clear with the concept of backtracking and I was thinking backtracking will be done only when we are trying to instantiate a variable like `like(1,X).` but now I am little bit more clear about this concept. Thanks again.

Comment: @Anil Mundra: Excellent! Happy to help.