# Results are not compareing with given facts

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

Using prolog make a code to get some compared outputs but some outputs not working properly. seems those are not comparing with facts. here the code

```
fact(Fact) :- Fact,!.
fact(Fact):-Fact = ..[Rel, Arg1, Arg2],isa(Arg1, SuperArg).
SuperFact =..[Rel,SuperArg,Arg2].
covers(animal,skin).
isa(fish,animal).
isa(bird,animal).
isa(mammal,animal).
isa(shark,fish).
isa(salmon,fish).
isa(parrot,bird).
isa(penguin,bird).
speacial_organ(fish,gills).
travel(fish,swim).
birth(bird,lay_eggs).
special_organ(bird,wings).
travel(bird,fly).
birth(fish,lay_eggs).
birth(mammal,not_lay_eggs).
birth(shark,not_lay_eggs).
nature(shark,dangerous).
food(salmon,delicacy).
colour(parrot,green).
travel(penguin,walk).
```

this are the questions i want to find answers from this program

•   Can parrot fly?
•   What is the color of parrot?
•   Do parrots have skin?
•   Are sharks dangerous?

Comment: Computer says "no".  There are syntax errors in your program text.

Comment: When i run this there is no error show in system but some outputs are given false.. Eg can parrot fly is false

Comment: Typo: `speacial_organ` vs `special_organ`.

Comment: Any idea how to fix that

Comment: I get these errors: `src:2: Syntax error: Operator expected
 Singleton variables: [SuperFact,Rel,SuperArg,Arg2]
 No permission to modify static procedure `(=..)/2'`

Comment: group facts by predicate: put all `travel/2` together. then do the same for the other predicates, too.

Comment: @repeat did u find way to fix that..

Comment: don't forget to edit the question to show the code changes you make.

Comment: @repeat  but my one not showing any errors.. Anyway how can i get those answer to given questions

Comment: @repeat ok sure.. Thanks for reminding

Comment: which prolog system are you using?

Comment: shouldn't `isa/2` be transitive?

Comment: @repeat u mean prolog version?

Comment: @repeat 7.3.2 wieldmaker

Comment: yes, name and version. (e.g., SICStus Prolog version 4.3.2 64-bit)

Comment: @repeat swi-prolog version 7.2.3 by jan Wielemaker

Comment: @repeat yes that i using

Comment: coming to the actual content: as far as I can see, you are interested in the [tag:transitive-closure] of `isa/2`. it shows with the question "do parrots have skin": `covers(animal,skin)`, `isa(bird,animal)`, `isa(parrot,bird)`.

Comment: @repeat didnt get what u said.. Can u send example?

Comment: @repeat thanks.. That one got answer true.. How to get parrot can fly?

Comment: @repeat any way to  get this result using traversal?

Comment: @repeat thanks for ur answer but why parrot can fly is false.. Parrot is a bird and bird can fly then why its getting false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one: define the reflexive [transitive-closure](/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) of `isa/2` (named `is_a/2` in the following).

```
isa(fish,animal).
isa(bird,animal).
isa(mammal,animal).
isa(shark,fish).
isa(salmon,fish).
isa(parrot,bird).
isa(penguin,bird).

is_a(X, Y) :-
   closure0(isa, X, Y).
```

Step two: specify the remaining facts (grouped by predicate indicator).

```
covers(animal,skin).

special_organ(fish,gills).
special_organ(bird,wings).

travel(fish,swim).
travel(bird,fly).
travel(penguin,walk).

birth(bird,lay_eggs).
birth(fish,lay_eggs).
birth(mammal,not_lay_eggs).
birth(shark,not_lay_eggs).

nature(shark,dangerous).

food(salmon,delicacy).

colour(parrot,green).
```

Step three: let's ask some queries!

- > Can parrots fly?

  ```
  ?- is_a(parrot, X), travel(X, fly).
     X = bird
  ;  false.
  ```
- > What is the color of parrots?

  ```
  ?- is_a(parrot, X), colour(X, Colour).
     Colour = green, X = parrot         
  ;  false.
  ```
- > Do parrots have skin?

  ```
  ?- is_a(parrot, X), covers(X, skin).
     X = animal
  ;  false.
  ```
- > Are sharks dangerous?

  ```
  ?- is_a(shark, X), nature(X, dangerous).
     X = shark
  ;  false.
  ```

Comment: thanks for ur answer but why parrot can fly is false.. Parrot is a bird and bird can fly then why its getting false... Like vice shark is dangerous also same

Comment: @Chara. Do not get too excited about answers like `true ; false`. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013323/understanding-rules-false-as-answer .

Comment: But with that given facts it will be true.. Can u check why this all getting false

Comment: @Chara. Look closely! The binary operator `;` expresses "logical or"... Because of this `X = foo ; false` is logically equivalent to `X = foo`.

Comment: Are redundant answers by `is_a/2` intended?

Comment: Yes. got thanks my friend. how to get all answers like this is_a(parrot, X), colour(X, Colour).
Colour = green, X = parrot ;

Comment: answer will be like Colour = green  like shark = dangerous

Comment: Yes your answer is correct. but any other way to ask that questions to get answer like  shark = dangerous

Comment: @false. No. Initially I wanted to use `closure0/3`, but I made some errors... will edit! btw closure0 should have some redundant answers, too. memoization?

Comment: @repeat: It would mean to go a very steep step further ... Nice only as long as terms are ground.

Comment: "but I made some errors".. ok thanks friend when u edited to correct code let me know. i very close to answers with ur support..

Comment: and how to use cut operator to this code for stop coming false.

Comment: Ok will do. hope u got what i need exactly

Comment: i check with that code given this errors   1 ?- is_a(parrot, X), travel(X, fly).
ERROR: is_a/2: Undefined procedure: closure0/3
   Exception: (9) closure0(isa, parrot, _G1369) ? creep

Comment: @Chara. Include the source code of `closure0/3` (follow the link to the related question).

Comment: @Chara. Reload with `?- make.`

Comment: @repeat yes i did.. But same problem.. Can u edit with full code then i can copy and past to test

Comment: @Chara. Part1: `closure0(R_2,X0,X) :- closure0(R_2,X0,X,[X0]).
closure0(_,X,X,_).
closure0(R_2,X0,X,Xs):-call(R_2,X0,X1),maplist(dif(X1),Xs), closure0(R_2,X1,X,[X1|Xs]).`

Comment: @Chara. Part2: `is_a(X,Y):-closure0(isa,X,Y). isa(fish,animal).
isa(bird,animal).
isa(mammal,animal).
isa(shark,fish).
isa(salmon,fish).
isa(parrot,bird). isa(penguin,bird). covers(animal,skin). special_organ(fish,gills).
special_organ(bird,wings).
travel(fish,swim).
travel(bird,fly).
travel(penguin,walk).
birth(bird,lay_eggs).
birth(fish,lay_eggs).
birth(mammal,not_lay_eggs).
birth(shark,not_lay_eggs).
nature(shark,dangerous).
food(salmon,delicacy).
colour(parrot,green).`

Comment: Yes not its run without errors but answers are not for exact questions i need..
need to get answers like Colour = green ;
 
1 ?- is_a(parrot, X), travel(X, fly).
X = bird ;
false.

2 ?- is_a(parrot, X), colour(X, Colour).
X = parrot,
Colour = green ;
false.

3 ?- is_a(parrot, X), covers(X, skin).
X = animal ;
false.

4 ?- is_a(shark, X), nature(X, dangerous).
X = shark ;
false.

Comment: @Chara. Please give one full concrete example.

Comment: @Chara. Please work more diligently. Reading sentences like "Yes not its run without errors" is not fun.

Comment: @Chara. Would you care to share some of them?

Comment: Yes. i change the question asking type. wait i upload full details.